# array data changed without manipulation

Tags: javascript

I face an behavior which I cant explain but reproduce. I created an array of objects as a source data. I declared an second array and passing the data from the first. Now I can manipulate the second array without losing the original data.

But as soon as I manipulate the second array the source array changed too.

Please refer to the console output.

- The first *console.log(person)* before maniupulation of filterPerson (expected output ok).
- The second *console.log(person)* after maniupulation of filterPerson (expected output not ok) Since I did not adressed the first array those data shouldn´t be touched at all.

Can somebody explain me this?

```js
var person = [{"name": "Abby", "age": "22"}, {"name": "Paul", "age": "28"}, {"name": "Susi", "age": "19"} ]
var filterPerson = []

filterPerson = person

console.log(person)

for (var element of filterPerson) {
    if (element.age != 22) {
        element.age = 18
  }
}

console.log(person)

console.log(filterPerson)
```

Comment: Objects in JS are copied by reference. So `filterPerson = person` makes 2 variable pointing to same memory location. For your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Damn I did not know that. Thanks Rajesh, how can I deal with it in case I need both values?

Comment: Check the linked post. You'll get what you need